Trigger animation when another starts in motion
I am using motion to animate a background color whenever the variable colorHex changes, which works nicely. I would also like to scale up and back down each time the color changes. For this I've used scale: [1, 2, 1] however because the value never changes, it only runs on the initial animation. How can I ensure it retriggers whenever colorHex changes?
<motion.div
  transition={{ duration: 0.3, delay: offset * 0.1, ease: "easeOut" }}
  animate={{
    backgroundColor: colorHex,
    scale: [1, 2, 1],
  }}
  ...


Note that the only work around I've found is to set the scale to a new (very slightly different) value when the color value changes.


I think you can re-trigger the animation whenever the value changes by giving the "key" parameter to motion.div. I would be very happy if you could let me know if "key={colorHex}" works.

@BatuhanZorbeyZengin unfortunately that results in a complete remount of the component, so it loses its current state.Changing its key is like telling React it's a new instance.

Best I can do it add a very small random value to the first scale value whenever the backgroundColor changes. This causes the animation to retrigger.

Hey, just updated the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/79285234/9640177

First, you can trigger "manual" animations by using useAnimate:
  const [colorHex, setColorHex] = useState(getRandomColor());
  const [scope, animate] = useAnimate();

  const handleClick = () => {
    setColorHex(getRandomColor());
    animate(scope.current, { scale: [1, 2, 1] });
  };

  return (
    <motion.div
      ref={scope}
      onClick={handleClick}
      transition={{ duration: 0.3, delay: offset * 0.1, ease: "easeOut" }}
      animate={{
        backgroundColor: colorHex,
        scale: [1, 2, 1],
      }}
    >
      Hello World!
    </motion.div>
 )

Now that you have control on how to trigger the animation, you can just use React.useEffect to listen for changes on your colorHex:
export default function App() {
  const [colorHex, setColorHex] = useState(getRandomColor());
  const [scope, animate] = useAnimate();

  useEffect(() => {
    animate(scope.current, { scale: [1, 2, 1] });
  }, [colorHex]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setColorHex(getRandomColor());
  };

  return (
    <motion.div
      onClick={handleClick}
      ref={scope}
      transition={{ duration: 0.3, delay: offset * 0.1, ease: "easeOut" }}
      animate={{
        backgroundColor: colorHex,
        scale: [1, 2, 1],
      }}
    >
      Hello World!
    </motion.div>
  );
}

Here is a small repro with the full code.
